# Compare multiple values based on cell Value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a 3 datasets.

Master dataset have

```
A    B    C      D
11   T    Jim    India
12   U    Mary   UK
13   V    Bob    US
14   P    Peter  India
```

India dataset

```
A    B     H    K      
10   11    T    Jim    
10   13    0    Krestel  
10   14    P    Peter   
10   15    L    Robert
```

If the D coulmn had India then the details of columns A, B and C should match that in India dataset with coulmn B, H and K respectively. (The combination of the column A, B and C should present in Dataset- India, If not hoghlighted or add comment in last column of master dataset)

I have been doing this manually by adding several helper columns in all the datasets using concatenation and then using vlookup.

Is it possible to automate this process using vba?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear since, for instance, the dataset showing columns B, H and K is not being provided. Edit your question and make it clearer.

Comment: Done the corrections, I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think that you can achieve this through spreadsheet functions alone, without the need of VBA. Check the usage of the function VLOOKUP.

The idea would be to deploy a formula in, say, column "E" of the Master dataset that would check for an entry in the relevant *country* dataset matching the values of A, B and C. You will need to **build** the reference to the range VLOOKUP uses taking into account the country name.

Hope this serves you as a good guide.

Comment: I have already mentioned this in the post that I'm doing this since last few months using vlookup and helper columns and now the number of countries + frequency of the activity is increased that was the only reason I wished to make it automatic process. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: OK, I missed that part. In that case, the only think you need is a very, VERY small VBA that would replicate your manual operations (e.g. copying a formula into a dynamic range). Good luck!!